# Load Factor of HashTable with linked list chaining

Tags: python, hash

Give a true or false with your explaination

For hash tables with linked-list chaining, the load factor λ corresponds to the fraction of buckets
in the hash table that are not empty

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: It's a book question that I wanted to confirm.

Comment: Welcome to SO. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask